# How to set overflow hidden only on one side of the image with CSS and keep it responsive at the same time?

Tags: html, css, overflow, clip-path

I have an image and I need to set a coloured circle shape background behind it, while setting the overflow hidden only on the bottom part of the image. The image is rectangle shape and the background is circle. I have read all the similar articles, but because it needs to be a circle shape background I couldn't find a solution. I have tried to solve it with:

- overflow: hidden
- z-index
- clip-path

This is what I am trying to achieve above [image]

And this is the simplified code:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 420px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 420px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x400" />
<div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

donc make the container a circle, draw it as background then add the radius only at the bottom:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 420px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 420px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,red 98%,#0000);
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x400" />
<div>
```